# instance of primative (wrapper)

Tags: java, casting, primitive-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining if an Object is of primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709961/determining-if-an-object-is-of-primitive-type)

This may sound moronic, but please forgive me, I'm working with moronic code.  What is the best way, given a collection of objects, to identify which are primitives, or more accurately, wrappers around primitives.

Suppose I want to print all primitives:

```
HashMap<String,Object> context = GlobalStore.getContext(); // Some bizarre, strangely populated context
for(Entry<String,Object> e : context.entrySet()){
   if(e.value() instanceof PRIMITIVE){ // What goes here?
        System.out.println(e);
   }
}
```

Is this possible, other than by enumerating all primitives one by one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The excellent [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) project provides a [Primitives.isWrapperType(Class)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.html) which could be used as:

```
Primitives.isWrapperType(e.value().getClass())
```

Comment: writing a 2-line method would do the same thing

Comment: Huzzah for Guava, thanks, that's exactly what I needed!  Much more elegant than a home-brewed solution.

Comment: Or you can just extract what you need here https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.java (but it's bad ^^)

Comment: Personally much cleaner to just use the library; fortunately, I already am, so it's an easy solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either check each possible primitive, or, if you know that there won't be any BigXxx or AtomicXxx you can also check:

```
if(e.value() instanceof Number || e.value() instanceof Boolean || e.value() instanceof Character)
```

[List of subclasses of `Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html):

> `AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short`

[List of primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2):

> boolean, byte, short, int, long, char, float, double

But considering that there are only 8 primitive types, you might as well check them all and put that test in a utility method.

ps: Note that Guava and the answers linked in the possible duplicate also include Void, which is consistent with the fact that `System.out.println(void.class.isPrimitive());` prints true.