# Control return of Type of method in Java

Tags: java, primitive

I have a bean with many get but i want to create a generic method that takes this bean and controls the types of the return for its get.

How i can say (boolean method??) that a get method return a primitive data or an Object?

```
class A { int one; People two;  //get method of one and get method of two }
```

i want a method that say:  type of one is primitive; type of two is not primitive

thank you

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking, you should update the question and add some code to clarify

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you need to use the wrapper classes like Integer, Boolean to be able to return a primitive as an object.

Comment: It is possible that what you want to do is not good design practice, and that you really want to do something else. Please explain a bit more the background behind what you want to do.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709961/determining-if-an-object-is-of-primitive-type OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039080/java-how-to-determine-if-type-is-a-primitive-wrapper-string-or-other

Answer (score 0):

You can change the return type of the method to a user defined object or a collection and set the value in to the object and return it.

That way you can return any object you want.

In your case you can have a user defined object with private instance variable of all the data types that you might expect and have public getter and setter methods and a method to check what values are not null and return the value.

Answer (score 0):

if primitive it don't have getClass() method else it has.