# Detect a boxing class

Tags: java

Is there a way to know if a given class is a class that boxes a primitive type or do I have to make an ugly method like this :

```
public boolean isBoxingClass(Class clazz){
  String simpleName=clazz.getSimpleName();
  switch(simpleName){
    case "Integer":
    case "Long":
    case "Boolean":
    case "Double":
    case "Float":
      return true;
    default :
      return false;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

If finally opted for this solution :

```
public static final List<Class> BOXING_CLASSES= Arrays.asList(new Class[]{
      Integer.class,
      Long.class,
      Short.class,
      Boolean.class,
      Double.class,
      Float.class,
      Character.class,
      Void.class,
      Byte.class});

public static boolean isBoxing(Class clazz){
  return BOXING_CLASSES.contains(clazz);
}
```

Comment: What about `Character`?

Comment: That would return `true` for `my.package.Integer`! It's better to do it like this `class == Integer.class || class == Long.class || ...` (or equivalent, a `Set<Class<?>>` would come in handy).

Comment: @Ziyao Wei : I want a method precisely because I do not want to miss some cases like this ;)

Comment: @Joachim Sauer : Thank you for raising this issue, I also missed this one :)

Comment: Jon Skeet said no you cannot have a simpler way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709961/determining-if-an-object-is-of-primitive-type

Comment: Small note, you should use a Set instead of a List, at this scale it won't make any performance difference but still a Set is the proper structure to use here.

Comment: that seems to be good. Do you have a nice way to declare and init this set in a simple line ? (an equivalent to something like Sets.asSet())

Comment: @adenoyelle: `new HashSet(Arrays.asList(...))` is the shortest you can get within JDK-classes only (also you can skip the `new Class[]`, as `asList()` is a var-args method). Guava adds `ImmutableSet.of()` (but if you use Guava, you can just use the `Primitives` class).

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way I could think of. The wrapper classes are present only in `java.lang` package. And apart from the wrapper classes, no other class in `java.lang` has a variable named `TYPE`. You could use that to check whether a class is Wrapper class or not.

```
public static boolean isBoxingClass(Class<?> clazz)
{
    String pack = clazz.getPackage().getName();
    if(!"java.lang".equals(pack)) 
        return false;
    try 
    {
        clazz.getField("TYPE");
    } 
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) 
    {
        return false;
    }           
    return true;        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about looking if the class implements Number, or if it's Character, or Boolean (I think those are the only options)?

```
public boolean isBoxingClass(Class clazz)
{   
    return Number.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) ||
           Character.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) || 
           Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}
```

In this case you get true for eg. BigDecimal and AtomicInteger as well, not sure if that's what you want. But in any case you don't need to go through getSimpleName().

Comment: Returns `true` for `BigDecimal.class`.