# Java is there a simple way to check if a type is wrapper type of primitive types?

Tags: java

In other words, check if a type is one of Integer, Double, Float, Long, Byte, Short, Boolean, Char

Comment: Why do you even need that? Autoboxing and Unboxing works pretty well in Java. Can you describe your usage scenario?

Comment: Take a look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709961/determining-if-an-object-is-of-primitive-type

Comment: I guessing you dont want to make a big if-else block with tons of instanceof tests?

Comment: You can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709961/determining-if-an-object-is-of-primitive-type Or check Spring's ClassUtils: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html#isPrimitiveOrWrapper(java.lang.Class)

Comment: please vote to close.

Comment: @Sayem when using reflection. java.lang.reflect.Field#getType return int.class for a int field and return Integer.class for a Integer Field, so I think we need to distinguish when int and integer are both allowed for a ambiguous field