# How to test if an object is primitive type or an array of primitive type in Java?

Tags: java

Here the function signature I would like to implement.

```
public boolean isBaseTypeOrArray(Object obj){~}
```

I want to return true only if obj is of one of the following types.

```
boolean or boolean[]
byte or byte[]
short or short[]
int or int[]
long or long[]
float or float[]
double or double[]
char or char[]
java.lang.String or String[]
```

For a lone value checking if it is instance of one of the wrapper classes (Integer, Float, ...) or String should work because of auto boxing but I do not know how to check for the array case. Any ideas?

Comment: How would this be used and why?

Comment: You will not be able to determine if argument was primitive because it will be autoboxed to Object type. You will have to create separate methods for primitive types.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709961/determining-if-an-object-is-of-primitive-type

Comment: The simplest way might be to make a big list of 18 `Class` objects and check if the object's class is in the list.

Comment: Are you actually going to be passing primitives to this function? You can't actually pass a primitive to this function without already knowing that it's a primitive. (Strictly speaking, you can't pass a primitive to this function at all, since it'll be boxed before it reaches the function.) While it's possible to determine whether a value is one of the 8 box types, boxes aren't primitives. Also, `String` isn't primitive.

Comment: @PaulBellora I am receiving collections of `Object` and I need to test them.

Comment: @user2357112 I know about String and I know this will be a separate case.

Comment: Why not just overload the function with these parameters? and write seperate functions to accept your inputs? Then you can write a common function for your business logic? That is one way of doing it right.

Comment: @Hrishikesh please see my comment to PaulBellora

Comment: if the default value of the object is != null then return true? I guess this might work, any comments

Answer (score 15):

- To test if object is an array just `getClass()` and see if it `isArray()`.
- To get type of elements array is declared to hold use `getComponentType()` on Class instance.
- To test if some type is primitive you can use `isPrimitive()`.
- If you want to check if type represents String just use `equals(String.class)`.

So to test if Object represents String, or an array of Strings, or array of primitive type you can use

```
public static boolean isBaseTypeOrArray(Object obj) {
    Class<?> c = obj.getClass();
    return  c.equals(String.class) 
         || c.equals(String[].class)
         || c.isArray() && c.getComponentType().isPrimitive();
}
```

Problem with above method is that it can't accept purely primitive type values because its parameter is declared as `Object obj`. This means that even if we pass primitive type value like `isBaseTypeOrArray(1)`, the `int` value 1 will be autoboxed to reference type `Integer` also representing 1.

To accept arguments of purely primitive types (like `int` instead of generated `Integer`) we need to overload this `isBaseTypeOrArray(Object obj)` method with versions accepting primitive types - like `isBaseTypeOrArray(int obj)`. Such methods can immediately return `true` as result, because fact that they ware invoked means that primitive type value was passed as argument (remember that `isBaseTypeOrArray(Object)` would handle all non-primitive types).

So to handle all primitive types we need to *add* below methods:

```
public static boolean isBaseTypeOrArray(boolean obj) {return true;}
public static boolean isBaseTypeOrArray(byte    obj) {return true;}
public static boolean isBaseTypeOrArray(short   obj) {return true;}
public static boolean isBaseTypeOrArray(char    obj) {return true;}
public static boolean isBaseTypeOrArray(int     obj) {return true;}
public static boolean isBaseTypeOrArray(long    obj) {return true;}
public static boolean isBaseTypeOrArray(float   obj) {return true;}
public static boolean isBaseTypeOrArray(double  obj) {return true;}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think, you should dynamically get and test a class description of your value:

```
if (obj.getClass().equals(Boolean.class)) {
    //...
}
//...
if (obj.getClass().equals(boolean[].class)) {
    //...
}
//...
if (obj.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isBaseTypeOrArray(new int[5]));
}

public static boolean isBaseTypeOrArray(Object obj){
   return (obj.getClass().getComponentType().equals(int.class)||
           obj.getClass().getComponentType().equals(byte.class));
}
```

Comment: He accepts an Object as an argument, so it can't be a value of primitive type.

Comment: How would you test if it is an array of int? for example.

Comment: @ɭɘɖɵʊɒɼɖ江戸, I've already wrote in my answer how to test if it's an array.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

```
public static boolean isPrimitiveArray(Object obj) {
    return obj != null 
        && obj.getClass().isArray() 
        && obj.getClass().getComponentType() != null 
        && obj.getClass().getComponentType().isPrimitive();
}
```