# Object in Object to HashMap with reflection

Tags: java, oop, reflection, hashmap, hierarchy

#### Project:

I am currently using a tool called [Netuno](https://www.netuno.org/) to develop an api, so to do the export of objects to json it is necessary to do the transformation of the object to HashMap, for this a method was developed in a parent class to export the object.

The method:

```java
   public Map<String, Object> export() {
        Object obj = this;
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                map.put(field.getName(), field.get(obj));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //todo e
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

This works, but only for simple objects.

#### My problem:

If the object has complex objects inside my method it has no ability to export them to HashMap either.

Example structure:

```java
public abstract class Master {
 public Map < String, Object >
  export () {
   Object obj = this;
   Map < String, Object > map = new HashMap < > ();
   for (Field field: obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    try {
     map.put(field.getName(), field.get(obj));
    } catch (Exception e) {
     //todo e
    }
   }
   return map;
  }
}

public class Foo extends Master {
 private int a;
 private int b;
 private String c;
 private Bar bar;
//...
}

public class Bar extends Master {
 private int q;
 private int w;
 private String e;
//...
}
```

I use it this way:

```
return new Bar(/*data*/).export();
```

Output:

```
{
  "a": 2,
  "b": 5,
  "c": "abc",
  "bar": "myproject.myPackage.Bar@XXXXX"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "a": 2,
  "b": 5,
  "c": "abc",
  "bar": {
    "q": 10,
    "w": 15,
    "e": "it works"
  }
}
```

Comment: There are libraries which will give you the result you want aswell (serializing an object into JSON/deserializing JSON into an object), like Gson/Jackson/plenty more, maybe something to look into?

Comment: You can add a condition if field.get(obj) is instance of Master cast to master and put in map export method result, but as Mark metioned there are libraries with that functionality

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the libraries :), but I was trying not to use them to not break the standard of my framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide if a value should me put plain in the map or recursively. Therefore you can use a simple method like this:

```
private boolean isSimpleType(Class<?> type) {
    return type.isPrimitive() ||
            Boolean.class == type ||
            Character.class == type ||
            CharSequence.class.isAssignableFrom(type) ||
            Number.class.isAssignableFrom(type) ||
            Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
}
```

This method returns `true` for all primitive types or the Wrapper objects, Strings and Enums. You can simply adjust that methods to fit your needs. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/709961/9662601) for more details on how to determine if a class is simple.

Now you can use to transform an object:

```
public Map<String, Object> convert(Object object) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            if (isSimpleType(field.getType())) {
                map.put(field.getName(), field.get(object));
            } else {
                map.put(field.getName(), convert(field.get(object)));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

You also can adjust this to do fir your `export` method.

The result for your example will be this:

```
{a=2, b=5, bar={q=10, e=it works, w=15}, c=abc}
```

Beside that I would strongly recommend using an library (like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)), which already does stuff like this by perfection. Here is the same solution using Jackson:

```
Map result = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(object, Map.class);
```

Or if you need type safety:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MapType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
Map<String, Object> result = mapper.convertValue(value, mapType);
```